# How can I make this material show up when the object is exported as .fbx and opened in 3d viewer or CSP

Tags: materials, .fbx

I only have the most surface level understanding of blender and I only need this model to mess around with in Clip Studio Paint which seems to only support .obj or .fbx files. As the model stands, the materials dont show up if I export the object as .fbx or .obj and then open it somewhere like 3d viewer, which I understand has to do with the material having any node other than the principled attached to the output. I get the feeling there's got to be a way to get that to happen but I'm not really sure where even to start to make that happen. Any help is much appreciated :)
[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The FBX exporter does not currently have a way to interpret Blender shaders fully into FBX shader format. I suggest getting your Blender shaders as close to how the target program shaders work as possible (such as baking procedural textures and the like to image textures if the target program does not support them), exporting the image textures involved, then re-creating the shaders in the target program. Critical things like UV maps are included in formats like FBX.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I figured that might be the case. If I could trouble you with one last question, would you happen to have any suggestions on the best ways to go about this? I'm mostly just interested in anything I can do to keep the teeth looking as close to the original as possible. I understand if its just not feasible I just feel like there Are steps I could take I just don't know about-Especially for the mixed shader? Here is an example of what each shader looks like on its own, I'm hoping maybe that will help in telling if there are any simpler ways to accomplish what I've done?

Comment: hm I don't know how to add an image to a comment I will just add it to the original question I guess...

Comment: That has more to do with how the target program’s shaders work, which I don’t know about. Sorry.

Comment: no worries thank you for your help XD